# Vue DevTools updating correctly but not browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm having a strange issue where the value found in Vue DevTools is correct.  It's declared in my data as expected.  The first time I click on "Edit" an item, the correct value shows up in my browser window as well.

However, if I click on "Edit" an item that has a different quantity, the same value shows up again even if it is incorrect (it should be prepopulating from the database).

Then, if I click back on the first "Edit" item again that value will get updated with the previous value!

**The craziest part** is that while my browser window is not showing the correct value, **the correct result is showing up in Vue DevTools at all times**!  The circled item in the image below is the UUID for the "Quantity" of 100, which is the correct value.  Yet 700 is showing up (the previous Edit item's value).  Anybody ever had this happen before and know what gives?

[image: Browser not matching (correct) value in Vue DevTools]

Here's some snippets of relevant code (it's from a Vue component using vue-resource, and this is taking place in a bootstrap modal in a Laravel project):

Vue JS

```
data() {
        return {
            selected_options: {},
            attributes: [],
        }
    },

methods: {

    editLineItem: function (line_item) {
            this.getProductOptionsWithAttributes(line_item.product_id);
            this.getPrepopulatedOptionsForLineItem(line_item.id);
    },

    getProductOptionsWithAttributes: function (product_id) {
            var local_this = this;
            var url = '/api/v1/products/' + product_id + '/options';
            this.$http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                local_this.attributes.$set(0, response.data);
            }, function (response) {
                // error handling
            });
        },

    getPrepopulatedOptionsForLineItem: function (id) {
            var local_this = this;
            var url = '/api/v1/line_items/' + id + '/options';
            this.$http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                Object.keys(response.data).forEach(function (key) {
                    Vue.set(local_this.selected_options, key, response.data[key]);
                });
            }, function (response) {
                //@TODO Implement error handling.
            });
        },
    }
```

HTML

```
<div v-for="(key, attribute) in attributes[0]" class="col-md-12 selectbox_spacing">
   <label for="option_{{$index}}">{{key}}</label><br/>
   <select class="chosen-select form-control" v-model="selected_options[key]" v-chosen="selected_options[key]" id="option_{{$index}}">
       <option v-for="option in attribute" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
   </select>
   </div>
<button v-on:click="editLineItem(line_item)">
```

Main.js vue-directive:

```
Vue.directive('chosen', {
    twoWay: true, // note the two-way binding
    bind: function () {
    $(this.el)
        .change(function(ev) {
            // two-way set
            //this.set(this.el.value);

            var i, len, option, ref;
            var values = [];
            ref = this.el.selectedOptions;

            if(this.el.multiple){
                for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
                    option = ref[i];
                    values.push(option.value)
                }
                this.set(values);

            } else {
                this.set(ref[0].value);
            }

        }.bind(this));
    },
    update: function(nv, ov) {
        // note that we have to notify chosen about update
        $(this.el).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
});

var vm = new Vue({
    el      : '#wrapper',

    components: {
        LineItemComponent
    }
});
```

Script in edit.blade.php file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#lineItemModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $('.chosen-select', this).chosen('destroy').chosen();
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using a select plugin like `bootstrap-select` or similar? If so, you may need to call a method like `.refresh()` after setting a new value programmatically to update the UI to show the new selection.

Comment: I think we may need some more code to solve this.  Sample DB response, code for select box would help.  Also it is good to pre-define the available values in your `data` options, ie. `Quantity` key should have a value off the bat if you want to use it with `v-model`

Comment: @Jeff I added some more HTML.  Quantity is not used as the v-model.  DB response is fine as you can see since it's getting all the way to Vue DevTools okay.

Comment: @DelightedD0D YES, excellent observation - I am using chosen-select and am using a vue-directive called v-chosen that is supposed to help.  I will add that directive above as well.

Comment: @DelightedD0D added a lot more code

Comment: Where your directive has `.trigger("chosen:updated");`, can you try changing that to  `.trigger("change");` or possibly `.trigger('liszt:updated');`  ? From searching, it seems the command can depend on the version you are using.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Thank you for the suggestions, but unfortunately, neither of those worked.  Does the last code snippet I added above maybe have something to do with it (the script in edit.blade.php file)?  Or are you fairly certain it's the vue-directive?

Comment: It could be possible that that is the cause. What is the reason fro destroying chosen when the modal opens? If it is just to clear the old values, could you try updating it with an empty array of options instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default, custom directives have a priority of `1000`. v-model has a [priority](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/directives/priorities.js) of `800` meaning it's evaluated after v-chosen when the template is compiled.

My Assumption is now: this is also affecting the update.

What I mean by that: I think `$(this.el).trigger("chosen:updated");` in the v-chosen update method is called before v-model did refresh the `selected` attribute on the list of `<option>` elements -  and that's where chosen checks for the new selected value.

Long story short: try this:

```
Vue.directive('chosen', {
    priority: 700, // Priority lower than v-model
    twoWay: true, // note the two-way binding
    bind: function () {
    ....
```

Comment: That fixed the problem!  Thank you for the solution.  Where (in the docs) did you learn about this priority attribute?  thanks again!

Comment: It's in the guide, in the chapter about "custom directives". The priority numbers are from cue source on github